# Webpack 4. ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: webpack

I have **webpack.config.js**:

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        main: ['./src/js/main.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [ 'script-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['env'] }
                }]
            },           
        ]
    },
    target: 'web'
};
```

In the file **main.js** I added `import $ from "jquery"`, because I use there jQuery:

```js
import $ from "jquery";
$(document).ready(function () {
...
});
```

But the browser shows an error: `ReferenceError: require is not defined.`

Comment: I have the exact same problem (I am not using jQuery though). Did you figure out why this happens? I noticed that if I add `type: 'javascript/auto'` to the `babel-loader` configuration this no longer happens. But I am not sure why would that be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try remove "target: 'web'" and don't set anything with 'target' attribute

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        main: ['./src/js/main.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/js/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [ 'script-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['env'] }
                }]
            },           
        ]
    },
    // target: 'web' => remove this line
};
```